# ООП: переопределение vs определение абстрактного метода

Tags: php, ооп

Подскажите, какой подход более грамотный, и почему:

```
<?php
    class base{
      function show(){
        return 'one';
      }
    }

    class one extends base{}
    class two extends base{
      function show(){
        return 'two';
      }
    }

    $one = new one();
    $two = new two();

    echo $one->show();
    echo $two->show();
```

VS

```
<?php
    abstract class base{
      abstract function show();
    }

    class one extends base{
      function show(){
        return 'one';
      }
    }
    class two extends base{
      function show(){
        return 'two';
      }
    }

    $one = new one();
    $two = new two();

    echo $one->show();
    echo $two->show();
```

Comment: а чем они отличаются? а, вот теперь видно

Comment: Зависит от задачи :)

Comment: Второй. Абстрактный класс не должен ничего знать о наследниках, он должен предоставлять функционал, который могут использовать наследники. В данном случае он пытается угадать, что от него будут хотеть наследники.

Comment: @Etki, в первом случае класс не абстрактный

Comment: @Grundy окей, можно убрать это слово

Comment: @Etki, таким образом остается обычный класс, который не знает о наследниках и просто работает :-) в итоге все одно и то же

Comment: @Grundy как раз-таки знает

Comment: @Etki, если то про _return 'one';_ то можно считать просто совпадением заменить на _return 'base';_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни первый вариант, ни второй. Вам нужен интерфейс.

```
interface Showable {
    function show();
}

class One implements Showable {
    public function show() {}
}

class Two implements Showable {
    public function show() {}
}
```

Абстрактный класс нужен в том случае, если у вас есть общая реализация для нескольких потомков.

При использовании интерфейсов, вы можете, например, написать класс, реализующий несколько интерфейсов.

Почитайте про [принципы проектирования SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). В особенности, про принцип подстановки и принцип разделения интерфейса.

Answer (score 0):

Я из другого языка, но попытаюсь ответить так: если вам не нужно создавать экземпляр класса, но требуется описать класс с общей функциональностью, при этом реализовав некоторые методы, то абстрактный класс. В наследниках вы можете переопределить нужные методы и т.д. Скорее всего это удобно для больших проектов, где есть некоторая функциональность, которую желательно не реализовывать каждый раз самому, а просто определить наследника. С другой стороны, если вам нужно создавать экземпляр вашего базового класса и этим вы не нарушите никакую логику приложения, никто не запретит вам реализовать второй вариант) При этом в абстрактных классах не нужно указывать, что их возможно переопределить,а вот в базовых надо(virtual методы c# к примеру). Все зависит от удобства и привычки=)